# How to check if the fetched message is an embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to edit a message, but I want to check if its an embed or not. If it is I want to edit the description of the embed. I don't know how to check if its an embed, and then edit the description. I couldn't find anything on google. Heres my current code (it currently only works, if its not an embed.):

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(sentId)
    .then(msg => {
                                                
        const fetchedMsg = msg;
        fetchedMsg.edit(collected.first().content);                                       

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.embeds` will be an empty array if there are no embeds.

```js
if (!message.embeds[0]) return;
```